# images not showing on cherrypy project

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am unable to get images to show on my cherrypy project.
I've tried looking at other similar questions posted on stackoverflow but still cannot get it to work.

My code:

```
class my_class():
    def index(self):

        html_script = '''<img src="resources/file.gif">'''

        return(html_script)
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host' : '0.0.0.0', 'server.socket_port': 8080, '/images': {'tools.staticdir.on': True, 'tools.staticdir.dir': '/home/user/cherrypy/site/resources'}})

cherrypy.quickstart(my_class())
```

The file does exist in the directory

Thanks

Comment: How do you serve the static files?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should really read more about HTTP-Servers work. You serve your static files which are located at `/home/user/cherrypy/site/resources` at the URL `/images`.

```
class my_class():
    def index(self):

        html_script = '''<img src="/images/file.gif">'''

        return(html_script)
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host' : '0.0.0.0',
    'server.socket_port': 8080,
    '/images': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': '/home/user/cherrypy/site/resources'}
})

cherrypy.quickstart(my_class())
```